# Spring bean resolution based on unique constructors

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, constructor

Would be grateful if you could help me with the following.
Suppose I have the following classes and interface:

```
public interface BaseType {
     public void method();
}

@Component
@Scope(SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public class BaseTypeImpl implements BaseType {
    private int num;

    public BaseTypeImpl(int num) {
        this.num = num;
    }

    @Override
    public void method() {
        System.out.println(num);
    }
}

@Component
@Scope(SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public class ChildBaseTypeImpl extends BaseTypeImpl {

    String mes;

    public ChildBaseTypeImpl(int num, String mes) {
        super(num);
        this.mes = mes;
    }

    @Override
    public void method() {
        super.method();
        System.out.println(mes);
    }
}

@Component
@Scope(SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public class SecondaryTypeImpl implements BaseType {

    private String str;

    public SecondaryTypeImpl(String str) {
        this.str = str;
    }

    @Override
    public void method() {
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

In result, I have 3 classes implementing 1 interface.
All the classes have non-default constructor with a different parameters.
Is there a way to make Spring lookup for a correct bean by `BaseType` interface based on the constructor parameters?
I want to do this:

```
ApplicationContext ctx = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("beans.xml");
ctx.getBean(BaseType.class, 11); //Should return instance of BaseTypeImpl class object, since it has constructor taking int
```

or like this:

```
ctx.getBean(BaseType.class, 11, "hello!"); //Should return instance of ChildBaseTypeImpl
```

Trying to do this will result in exception:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type 'springtest.BaseType' available: expected
>   single matching bean but found 3:
>   baseTypeImpl,childBaseTypeImpl,secondaryTypeImpl

It seems like there is no straightforward way to do this.

But maybe is it possible to get all classes, that are assignable from a `BaseType`, find appropriate constructors among them and then call `getBean` method with the `*Impl` class as a first parameter?

UPDATED

Thanks everyone for answering!
As pvpkiran mentioned, there is a way to get class of bean by bean name.
This opens the door for reflection, which solves the problem, here's the sample code:

```
public class App {

    static ApplicationContext ctx = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("beans.xml");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BaseType beanByInterface = getBeanByInterface(BaseType.class, "Hello!");
        System.out.println(beanByInterface.getClass());
    }

    public static <T> T getBeanByInterface(Class<T> interf, Object... params) {

        BeanDefinitionRegistry bdr = new SimpleBeanDefinitionRegistry();
        ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner s = new ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner(bdr);

        TypeFilter tf = new AssignableTypeFilter(interf);
        s.addIncludeFilter(tf);
        s.scan("springtest"); //Sample project package name
        String[] beans = bdr.getBeanDefinitionNames();

        for(String b : beans) {
            Class<?> type = ctx.getType(b);
            MAIN: for(Constructor cons : type.getConstructors()) {
                if (cons.getParameterCount() == params.length) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < cons.getParameterCount(); i++) {
                        if (!params[i].getClass().equals(cons.getParameterTypes()[i])) { //Will fail comparing primitive and boxed types, just leaving like this for simplicity
                            continue MAIN;
                        }
                    }
                    return (T) ctx.getBean(type, params);
                }
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

The code is buggy, but this is just to show the concept.
Having the beans classes I can get the right bean, that has the needed constructor.

This sample outputs "class springtest.SecondaryTypeImpl"

But I believe this should be the common problem that is covered in some utils.
I don't want to invent the bicycle, but still can't find the solution.

UPDATED 2

Seems like there is no such solution in existing libs, since it's not the best practice.
Anyway, here's the updated method, maybe someone will find it useful.

```
public static <T> T getBeanByInterface(Class<T> interf, Object... params) {

    String[] beans = ctx.getBeanNamesForType(interf);

    for(String beanName : ctx.getBeanNamesForType(interf)) {
        Class<?> type = ctx.getType(beanName);
        Class<?>[] paramTypes = new Class[params.length];
        //Getting params types
        for (int i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
            paramTypes[i] = params[i].getClass();
        }

        if (ConstructorUtils.getMatchingAccessibleConstructor(type, paramTypes) != null) {
            return (T) ctx.getBean(type, params);
        }

    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can get it by Type and arguments, you can get it from bean nameand arguments. Will that be okay for you?

Comment: Hi pvpkiran! Did I get it right - I can get the bean class by it's name? Yes, I think this should work for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

BeanFactory has following `getBean()` declaration

```
Object getBean(String name, Object... args) throws BeansException;
<T> T getBean(Class<T> requiredType) throws BeansException;
<T> T getBean(Class<T> requiredType, Object... args) throws BeansException;
Object getBean(String name) throws BeansException;
<T> T getBean(String name, Class<T> requiredType) throws BeansException
```

As you can see here, there is no declaration for class type, bean name and arguments(which is what you are looking for).

But you can get the bean using bean name and arguments.

```
 ApplicationContext ctx = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("beans.xml");

 ChildBaseTypeImpl childBaseTypeImpl = (ChildBaseTypeImpl) ctx.getBean("childBaseTypeImpl", 11, "hello");
 BaseTypeImpl basetypeImpl = (BaseTypeImpl)  ctx.getBean("baseTypeImpl", 11, );
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can't use constructor arguments to differentiate your beans, as @alexlys noted. But you could do something different with the same result. Both approaches assumes that you could define what bean you need not in runtime but when you write the code.

- You could create beans with unique names and then get desired bean by
  name, not by interface
- You could add some marker interfaces like 
  `interface SecondaryType extends BaseType {//empty}`. Each bean will implement only one specific interface so you could instaniate beans using such iterfaces.